# Liquibase. How to track store procedures changes

Tags: liquibase

I'm a database developer. My main reason to start using Liquibase is to get the knowledge in what state is any of Lab or Production databases.

I can't understand how to work with stored procedures. Particularly, I don't understand how to track what procedures are included into current release.

The best practices state:

> Try to maintain separate changelog for Stored Procedures and use
>   runOnChange=”true”. This flag forces LiquiBase to check if the
>   changeset was modified. If so, liquibase executes the change again.

Does it state that I need to create a static file with all procedures, like procedures.xml?

How do I track what particular procedure is included into the sprint?

Answer (score 1):

You can keep your stored procedures in separate sql files and if any of them is changed during sprint include a reference to it with runOnChange=true into changelog for a sprint.